# Lost tables in Drupal site database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have Drupal site on my local server build using pressflow

I had problems with the xammp 1.7.4 server, so I delete everything except mysql and htdocs folders.

I installed the server again, but the drupal site didn't work again.

There are 186 tables in my Drupal database, but phpmyadmin shows only 119 InnoDB tables

The rest of the tables are MyISAM, but they didn't show in phpmyadmin and it looks like Drupal can't find them too

I don't know where is the actual problem and how to fix it. Help me please.

Comment: Please run this query and post it in your question: SELECT engine,COUNT(1) EngineTableCount FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') GROUP BY engine;

Comment: Please run this as well and post it in your question : SELECT IFNULL(table_schema,'Total') DB,COUNT(1) DBTableCount FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY table_schema WITH ROLLUP;

Comment: the first comment query returns InnoDB MyISAM PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA

Comment: Please show the counts from the second query

Comment: 186 tables in the database

Comment: Please show the counts from the first query (Number of InnoDB tables, number of MyISAM)

Comment: the first comment query returns InnoDB 349 MyISAM 433 PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 17

Comment: @M.B.Asfoor let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/595/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-m-b-asfoor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to check out the configuration of InnoDB.

You can start by running

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb';
SHOW ENGINES;
```

These will indicate whether or not InnoDB is running properly.

If InnoDB is disabled, it is more than likely that the log files need to be recreated.

As long as you keep ibdata, delete ib_logfile0, delete ib_logfile1, and set innodb_log_file_size to 170M in my.ini, you should be able to start mysql and have mysql rebuild new ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile0 to 170M each as suggested by [the article you mentioned in the chat room](http://www.nerdydork.com/restoring-mysql-innodb-files-on-windows.html).